# How do I use an NSTimer with the internal clock?

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried researching this, I must be looking in the wrong places or wording it incorrectly, however, my question is:

How do I use the NSTimer function with the iOS system's internal clock? I want to use a timer that works even when the app has been closed.

eg: set a timer to increase a score by 1 every second. The timer runs for 5 hours, and the user closes the app on their iPhone. How do I make it so that when the user opens the app in 6 hours for example, the task is completed, or if they open in 2 hours, the counter displays with 3 hours remaining?

If this can't be completed in Swift 2, but is a server side task or similar, any guidance is greatly appreciated as I can't seem to figure out how to approach this.

Answer (score 4):

You're approaching this problem incorrectly. You do not want an `NSTimer` or anything similar. Don't need to do anything server side either (with a caveat below).

When the app closes, record the tasks that are running etc, and the time. When the app opens again, check the current time, and process whatever changes would have happened between those times, if it's 1 point per second, calculate the number of seconds that have past and add that many points etc.

The caveat with the server: Depending on what you're doing, you may not want users to be able to cheat, i.e., start a task, close the app, move the time on the device ahead 5 hours and reopen the app to gain 5 hours worth of points. A server can be used to prevent this sort of thing. Either using a server to check the real time, or storing the tasks on it etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will look into storing the current date/time and checking against that.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run code while the app is closed.

But what you are asking for doesn't need any code to be running.

When you start the timer, put the start time into the NSUserDefaults (as an example: but a proper store would be a better idea). You can run your timer normally while the app is running and the timer stops when the app terminates. When the app starts again, or comes back from the background, you just need to read the timer start date, compare it with the current time and restart your timer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am currently investigating using core data and/or NSUserDefaults.